# Smartgwt: How to get checkbox value on a listgrid?

Tags: checkbox, smartgwt, listgrid, ischecked

I've a listener on cellClick, I get the selected Record but I can't find a way to understand if this record is checked

Method ListGrid.isSelected(ListGridRecord) returns true if row is selected, not if is checked

My Code:

```
listGrid.setSelectionAppearance(SelectionAppearance.CHECKBOX);
            listGrid.addCellClickHandler(new CellClickHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onCellClick(CellClickEvent event) {

                    if(event.getColNum() == 0 && idMenu != null){
                        boolean isChecked = event.getRecord().???;

                        if(isChecked)
                            ....
                        else
                                                    ....
        }
```

I've tried also with event.getRecord().getAttributeAsBoolean("_checkField") with no success...

Comment: Smartgwt is a little bit far away for me now but If I undestand well you use `listGrid.setSelectionAppearance(SelectionAppearance.CHECKBOX);` to say "Hey I would like to indicate the record I selected by checking a dedicated checkbox" No? so why wanting to know if the checkbox you checked is checked? But perhaps I misunderstood what you mean....

Comment: Hi... thx for your reply... Cause I can also uncheck the record, unfortunately the listener is the same for check and uncheck event and I need to retrieve the correct check value to execute a task rather than other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simply solution...

My task is solved using a special boolean field in the DataSource named, for example, "checked"
In ListGrid I've a field "checked", and with a RecordClickHandler I can manage check or uncheck event.

DataSource code:

DataSourceBooleanField checkField = new DataSourceBooleanField("checked");

ListGrid code:

listGrid.addRecordClickHandler(new RecordClickHandler() {

```
@Override
public void onRecordClick(RecordClickEvent event) {
                Record rec = event.getRecord();

                boolean checked = rec.getAttributeAsBoolean("checked");

                if(checked){
                  ...   
                }else{
                   ...
                }

                rec.setAttribute("checked", !checked);

                catPgrid.saveAllEdits();
                catPgrid.refreshFields();
            }
        });


        ListGridField checkField = new ListGridField("checked", "Sel");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe getSelectedRecords() method would help you!

Here is an API reference: http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGrid.html#getSelectedRecords()

Definitely this will provide all records which are selected (using checkbox) but there should be some values which you could use for identifying each record uniquely!

Comment: Finally i've used a Vector to save checked record and compare with new selection... with getSelectedRecords() I obtain an array of all records checked or only selected and this solution is deprecable cause i must do a for/while for each click to understand if my record become checked or unchecked...